# 'accordionHeader.addEventListener' is not a fuction

Tags: javascript

This code should make a slider open by clicking an icon(arrow) whenever i try to open that slider it gives me that error (accordionHeader.addEventListener is not a fuction)

```
const accordionItems = document.querySelectorAll('.value__accordion-item')

accordionItems.forEach((item) =>{
    const accordionHeader = item.querySelectorAll('.value__accordion-header')

    accordionHeader.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        const openItem = document.querySelector('.accordion-open')

        toggleItem(item)

        if(openItem && openItem!== item){
            toggleItem(openItem)
        }
    })
})

const toggleItem = (item) =>{
    const accordionContent = item.querySelectorAll('.value__accordion-content')

    if(item.classList.contains('accordion-open')){
        accordionContent.removeAttribute('style')
        item.classList.remove('accordion-open')
    } else{
        accordionContent.style.header = accordionContent.scrollHeight + 'px'
        item.classList.add('accordion-open')
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure `item.querySelectorAll('.value__accordion-header')` returns what you think it returns?

Comment: Please explain your question properly.

Comment: `item.querySelectorAll('.value__accordion-header')` returns an Array, so you need to iterate over it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const accordionHeader = item.querySelectorAll('.value__accordion-header')` returns a `NodeList` so `accordionHeader.addEventListener` will not work.

I think you're looking for `item.querySelector` instead. Change your code to this

```
const accordionItems = document.querySelectorAll('.value__accordion-item')

accordionItems.forEach((item) =>{
    const accordionHeader = item.querySelector('.value__accordion-header')

    accordionHeader.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        const openItem = document.querySelector('.accordion-open')

        toggleItem(item)

        if(openItem && openItem!== item){
            toggleItem(openItem)
        }
    })
})

const toggleItem = (item) =>{
    const accordionContent = item.querySelector('.value__accordion-content')

    if(item.classList.contains('accordion-open')){
        accordionContent.removeAttribute('style')
        item.classList.remove('accordion-open')
    } else{
        accordionContent.style.header = accordionContent.scrollHeight + 'px'
        item.classList.add('accordion-open')
    }

}
```